# NAT Masquerading second container network

Tags: nat, lxc, proxmox, masquerade

I have 1 public IP, and would like to share internet connection to LXC containers running Centos (in this setup) the host runs proxmox (debian based). If I understand correctly, i need NAT masquerading, the problem is, the second container I create does not get access to the network.

**Settings on the host :**

ifconfig :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:d9:1f:e8
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15789748 errors:0 dropped:3170 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6323926 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:13693916365 (12.7 GiB)  TX bytes:1077829250 (1.0 GiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:11041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:3907254 (3.7 MiB)  TX bytes:3907254 (3.7 MiB)

veth104i0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:b4:26:dc:aa:ac
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcb4:26ff:fedc:aaac/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:62852 (61.3 KiB)  TX bytes:883353 (862.6 KiB)

veth105i0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:69:8f:16:a3:40
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc69:8fff:fe16:a340/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:447158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:401684 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:46903237 (44.7 MiB)  TX bytes:5625117349 (5.2 GiB)

vmbr0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:c4:7a:d9:1f:e8
          inet addr:*public IP* Bcast:*****  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr:**** Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:503891 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:527129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5637105768 (5.2 GiB)  TX bytes:61721641 (58.8 MiB)

vmbr1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:69:8f:16:a3:40
          inet addr:10.10.10.254  Bcast:10.10.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b42e:2eff:fe1a:5640/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:447158 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:401684 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:40643025 (38.7 MiB)  TX bytes:5625117349 (5.2 GiB)
```

iptables -t nat -L

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.10.10.0/24       !10.10.10.0/24
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.10.10.0/24        anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.10.10.0/24       !10.10.10.0/24
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet dhcp
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 143.169.254.254
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 10.10.10.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.10.10.0
        broadcast 10.10.10.255
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up         iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-up         iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' ! -d '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down       iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         *public gateway* 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vmbr0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmbr1
xxx.xxx.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 vmbr0
```

**on both containers (private IP is different) :**

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.10.10.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1031   0        0 eth0
```

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2E:15:95:39:D1:17
          inet addr:10.10.10.4  Bcast:10.10.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2c15:95ff:fe39:d117/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12437 errors:0 dropped:38 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:665 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1106036 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:63024 (61.5 KiB)
```

/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.10.10.4
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.10.10.254
```

How do I get network to both containers, and how does a sysadmin generally find out whats running wrong here ?
I can ping from the first container to the host. But not from the second container to the host or the neighbor.

Comment: Have you configured a virtual adapter on the second host, and is it attached to `vmbr1`?

Comment: In the proxmox interface yes, the device pops up as veth104i0 on the host, in the node the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 is used and the ip is "taken"...

Comment: oh farts, you are correct, it was pointing to vmbr0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the proxmox interface there was a selection where one can set to what virtual bridge you can point. This was set wrong :

[image]